# Вопрос по свойствам Json

Tags: c#

Вот есть авто свойства, какой метод реализации будет лучше на Ваш счёт и правильнее?

```
internal class JsonProperty
{
  [JsonProperty("Day")]
  public string NewDay { get; set; }
  [JsonProperty("Month")]
  public string NewMonth { get; set; }
  [JsonProperty("Year")]
  public string NewYear { get; set; }
}
```

Нужно ли делать переопределение?

```
internal class JsonProperty
{
   public JsonProperty(string day, string month, string year)
   {
      this.NewDay = day;
      this.NewMonth = month;
      this.NewYear = year;
   }

   [JsonProperty("Day")]
   public string NewDay { get; set; }
   [JsonProperty("Month")]
   public string NewMonth { get; set; }
   [JsonProperty("Year")]
   public string NewYear { get; set; }
}
```

И вот ещё вариант с извлечением в интерфейс:

```
internal interface IJsonProperty
{
  string NewDay { get; set; }
  string NewMonth { get; set; }
  string NewYear { get; set; }
}

internal class JsonProperty : IJsonProperty
{
   public JsonProperty(string day, string month, string year)
   {
      this.NewDay = day;
      this.NewMonth = month;
      this.NewYear = year;
   }

   [JsonProperty("Day")]
   public string NewDay { get; set; }
   [JsonProperty("Month")]
   public string NewMonth { get; set; }
   [JsonProperty("Year")]
   public string NewYear { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: А типа DateTime недостаточно?

Comment: @adrug, Возможно, но мне нужно общее мнение окружающих =)

Comment: Во первых не стоит создавать класс с названием JsonProperty, когда такой есть уже у json.net. Во вторых, верно сказали выше, ваши 3 строки можно заменить одной. В третьих, а зачем вам интерфейс? Интерфейсы нужны для того, что бы в дальнейшем можно было реализовать то, что в них заложено, в вашем случае вы ведь реализуете это один раз и все. Для этого достаточно обычного класса, без интерфейсов.

Comment: Кхгм... Типа `DateTime` недостаточно! Нужно использовать `DateTimeOffset`! [DateTime vs DateTimeOffset](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4331189/5045688).

Answer (score 0):

Есть готовый тип DateTime, используйте его.

Ваш способ хранить по отдельным полям - это как лететь из Москвы в Санкт-Петербург через Владивосток. В программировании, как и в любой инженерной дисциплине стараются решить задачу минимальными средствами. Попробуйте мысленно довести идею до абсурда: вы б ещё отдельными битами хранили дату.

Есть готовый тип в языке, есть методы работы с ним - и надо взять это и пользоваться этим, а не городить огород из самопальных методов.

У вас есть какие-то требования, исходя из которых чётко и явно выводятся те способы решения, которые указаны? Нет, их нету - как минимум не описаны в вопросе, а просто где-то есть у вас в голове в виде несформулированных и неозвученных требований. А раз нету - значит идём к цели напрямую, без излишних углов.

Просто посмотрите на число апвоутов на комментарии

> А типа DateTime недостаточно?